# Why my program doesn't receive TCP packets before MQTT packet?

Tags: sockets, tcp, mqtt, wireshark

I have a simple program which uses sockets, listens on specific port (1883) and receives data from client's socket.

I compare received data with Wireshark - it works well.

There are a lot of other TCP packets around MQTT packet in Wireshark.

There is an example:

1) `mosquitto_pub -t test -m test`

2) In Wireshark, it looks like:

TCP packet
TCP packet
MQTT packet
TCP packet
TCP packet

3) But my program first receives MQTT packet and I'm asking; why doesn't it receive the first two TCP packets as well?

I don't mind that, I wanna receive only MQTT packet, but it seems weird to me and I'd like to know a reason.

I also have a filter in Wireshark, `tcp.port` on 1883.

Comment: TCP sync/ack packets...

Comment: I suggest you read about the OSI model (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)  TCP is the transport layer, MQTT is the application layer.